# Named routes not working in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have some named routes using the `as` parameter. Seems to work fine in 5.1, but when I use the same package in 5.2 it throws an error:

```
ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 307:
Route [/blog] not defined. (View: ...)
```

I've cleared all the caches to no avail.

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

Have dumped:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

But still doesn't work. When I do a `php artisan route:list` it seems ok to me:

```
+--------+----------+------------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI              | Name       | Action                                                         | Middleware |
+--------+----------+------------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | blog             | blog       | ...                                                            |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | blog/feed        | feed       | ...                                                            |            |
```

**EDIT:** To clarify one thing. I'm definitely using `route('blog')` when trying to generate the route. It's also working in Laravel 5.1 just fine. Not to mention it's with ALL the named routes not just `blog` in the particular example I presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message is saying that you're trying to access a route with the name "/blog", however, your route is named "blog" (no slash). Somewhere you have the code `route('/blog')`, and this is causing your error; it should be `route('blog')`.

Comment: I'm definitely using `route('blog')` AND it's working in Laravel 5.1 just fine. Not to mention it's with ALL the named routes not just `blog`.

Comment: Actually you are right, I was looking in the wrong place @patricus, thx.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue with Laravel 5.2.  I have 3 simple routes defined.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    if (!empty(Auth::user())) {
        return view('auth.zipline');
    } else {
        return view('no_auth.login');
    }
});

Route::get('/login', function () {
    return view('no_auth.login');
});

Route::get('/pricing', function () {
    return view('no_auth.pricing');
});
```

The no_auth.login view is present (Text that says 'Login').
The no_auth.pricing view is present (text that says 'Pricing')

The / route works.  I get the login view.

Neither of the other routes work.  Going straight to /login or /pricing give me 404 errors.  mod_rewrite is enabled on the server and I'm using the default Laravel 5.2 .htaccess file.

php artisan route:list looks like (notice the missing leading slashes?):

```
+--------+----------+---------+------+---------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI     | Name | Action  | Middleware |
+--------+----------+---------+------+---------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /       |      | Closure |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | login   |      | Closure |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | pricing |      | Closure |            |
+--------+----------+---------+------+---------+------------+
```

The Routes file definitely has the leading slashes for /login and /pricing.
I have run
    php artisan route:clear